# Connection to AWS MySql server over SSL

Tags: 7, database, ssl

Running Drupal 7 and trying to enable secure connection between my AWS EC2 and RDS server using SSL.

Php version 5.3.29

I have found some information suggesting the following setup but I'm unsure how to configure this given my own SSL certs and the single certificate bundle I have from amazon?

When I try the below config I get a 500 server error.

Any pointers much appreciated.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'database name',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'AWS RDS Endpoint',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
      'pdo' => array (
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/path_to_your/client-key.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/path_to_your/client-cert.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/path_to_your/ca-cert.pem',
                     ),
      ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: What errors do you get ? (in the error log)

Comment: On closer inspection (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) those PDO options only 'exist as of PHP 5.3.7'

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm actually getting a syntax error: 

unexpected ',' in /sites/default/settings.php on line 236

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out and required SSL via phpmyadmin admin interface for my users.

There are my Drupal database params

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'database name',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'AWS RDS Endpoint',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
      'pdo' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '<path to>/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem',
      ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: If it would be Azure, `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false` option would also be necessary. I've spent hours, didn't want anyone else does.

Comment: Well, at least I found it now, but I've certainly just spent hours on this as well... /sadlife

Comment: Thanks to [Onur kucukece](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/23714/onur-kucukkece). It doesn't work on AWS as well without the `( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false)` param

Comment: Thanks @SimonHanks for you comment. This actually save my time :) Cheers